# How to display contact name or display_name of contact in list off messeges

Tags: android-studio

How could I display the names of the following numbers in my Listview if the numbers are given in the loop.
    void FetchAllMessages(){
        msgList = new ArrayList<>();

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

        String from = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(from));
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
            if(phones.moveToFirst()){
              contactname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
              msgList.add(contactname);
            }else{
                msgList.add(from);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

There is no display in my android and it continue to crash.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't write code for no contacts check. Try this code

```
ContentResolver cr = cntx.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    //Query to get contact name
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    // If data data found in contacts
    ArrayList<String> msgList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    int k = 0;
    String name = "";
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur
            .getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        name = cur
            .getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        //Check contact have phone number
        if (Integer
            .parseInt(cur
                .getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        //Create query to get phone number by contact id
        Cursor pCur = cr
            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                    + " = ?",
                new String[]{id},
                null);
        int j = 0;
        while (pCur
            .moveToNext()) {
            // Sometimes get multiple data
            if (j == 0) {
            // Get Phone number
            phoneNumber = "" + pCur.getString(pCur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            if (phoneNumber.startsWith("+91")) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(3, phoneNumber.length());
            }
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {
               // Add contacts names to arrayList
                msgList.add(name.toString());

            }
            j++;
            k++;
            }
        }  // End while loop

        pCur.close();
        } // End if

    }  // End while loop

    } // End Cursor value check
    cur.close();
```